# Continuity of $T: (C[0, 1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}) \rightarrow (C[0,1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}$)

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

I have been thinking about the following exercise in functional analysis and I don't see how to approach it. It is as follows. Consider $$T: (C[0, 1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_p) \rightarrow (C[0,1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_p)$$ and let $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$ be the usual $L^p$ norm. Show that if there is a $p$ s.t. $T$ is continuous then this implies that $$\widehat{T}: (C[0, 1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}) \rightarrow (C[0,1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty})$$

is continous as well. I know that an operator is continuous if it is bounded. But I don't see how this related to i.) the space of continuous functions and ii.) the $L^p$ norms. How would one show this?

Comment: What is $\widehat T$?

Comment: $(C[0, 1], \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty})$ is a Banach space, so you can apply the closed graph theorem.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It seems like probably $\hat Tf=Tf$; we don't want to just call it $T$ because the domain and range are different, _because_ we changed the norm.

Comment: @GEdgar you should probably write that as an answer.

Comment: I should probably wait for Taufi to solve it.